# Outlook 2003 repeatedly prompts for username and password

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-7, exchange-2003, outlook

I have a few users with Outlook 2003 and Windows 7. Every time they open outlook, They repeatedly get asked for their username and password no matter how many times they are entered. Outlook goes directly into offline mode when clicking cancel. The users are able to view their mail through outlook web access. I can open their mailboxes on a different computer with outlook 2003.

I have recreated their outlook profile. 
I have check all the permissions on the mailbox. "Self" has all the permissions.
I have moved their mailbox between exchange servers (I have two). 
I have tried entering the details as "domain\username" and "server\username" and just "username"

I'm using exchange 2003 and server 2003.

Edit: I have a domain. They are able to login to windows with their active directory account .

Comment: You are missing the two most important details here: are those users using a domain joined computer? And are they actually logged in with their domain accounts? Maybe it's obvious (to you), but please add these details.

Comment: Can they login to OWA?

Comment: They can log into OWA.

Comment: Tried deleting the Outlook Profile and recreating it yet? I've seen O2003 do this before and it's just a corrupted profile.

Comment: Have you changed any settings in the GPO that corresponds to session encryption between the Outlook and the server?

Comment: I have discovered a workaround for the meantime is to change authenication in outlook to NTLM.

Answer (score 1):

We have run into this issue with users who have clicked the "remember this password" checkbox and then changed their passwords later.

On Windows 7 check the following to see if this fixes the issue:

`Control Panel` / `User Accounts` / `Manage your Credentials`

Make sure no windows credentials are saved there that are referencing your email (or sharepoint) servers.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like those particular workstations are having connectivity issues. Can these same users connect to the Exchange server from different workstations using their credentials? Do you have Outlook Anywhere enabled on the exchange server? What kind of connection are you establishing with your Exchange server? TCP/IP? HTTP?

First thing I would establish is that those workstations have network connectivity with either one of your Exchange servers.

**Edit:**

I noticted you are on a domain. Are their Active Directory Accounts tied directly to their Exchange accounts?